# How to create a file in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to write a shell script where I read a variable from environment. If the file pointed by it doesn't exist, I want to create it.

This file path could contain some intermediate non-existent directories, so these also need to be created. So neither mkdir -p works here nor simple touch works here.

What is the workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mkdir -p "`dirname $foo`"
touch "$foo"
```

`dirname` works on arbitrary paths; it doesn't check whether the path is in use (whether the file pointed to exists).

Comment: Beautiful, +1. "so neither mkdir -p works here nor simple touch works here" - we'll see about that, my pretty :-)

Comment: this will create the file in the wrong (current) directory. you don't need `basename`.

Comment: Thanks @knittl, thinko on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine both? `mkdir -p /directories/.... && touch /directories/file`

Comment: The `&` operator will not do what you wanted. You probably meant `&&`